# How to prevent spring boot from auto creating instance of bean 'entityManagerFactory' at startup?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am working on a Spring boot application that uses `Spring JPA` with `PostgreSQL`. I am using `@SpringBootTest(classes = <my package>.Application.class)` to initialize my unit test for a controller class.

The problem is that this is causing the `entityManagerFactory` bean (and many other objects related to jpa, datasource, jdbc, etc.) to be created which is not needed for unit tests. Is there a way to prevent Spring from automatically creating these objects till they are actually used the first time?

I spent a lot of time trying to load up only the beans I need for my unit test but ran into many errors. I am relatively new to Spring and I am hoping someone else has run into this before...and can help. I can post code snippets if needed.

**Update:** I am not sure if I should edit or answer my own question...choosing to edit since I ended up changing my approach to unit tests. I added this to my test config class.

```
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"api.controller", "api.config", "api.utils"})
  public class TestControllerConfig {
  }
```

and I mocked out the service and repository classes.

Comment: If it is a unit test then you don't need `@SpringBootTest` else it is an integration test and you want a full context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [disable auto configuration in spring-boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration) using `exclude` attribute of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestConfig {
}
```

**From `@EnableAutoConfiguration` documentation:**

*If the class is not on the classpath, you can use the **`excludeName`** attribute of the annotation and specify the fully qualified name instead. Finally, you can also control the list of auto-configuration classes to exclude via the **`spring.autoconfigure.exclude`** property.*

Comment: I added a config class, TestControllerConfig, as suggested by you above. Then I modified my test class as shown below. The datasource and JPA beans still get created. And if I remove the @SpringBootTest annotation, I start getting errors (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException) for every bean I need for my test to work. `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = com.tgt.merch.eno.transferorder.api.Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = com.tgt.merch.test.controller.config.TestControllerConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HealthControllerTest {`

Comment: Since you have answered my original question and it makes sense to me, I am going to accept it even though I solved my issue a different way. I am new to posting in SO so I am hoping it is ok to do this.

Comment: @rmulay it's good if you share how you fixed it, will be helpful for future readers.

Comment: I updated my original question with how I fixed it. Do you think I should add more details if it is not clear.